# How to install conda package from custom file channel in Docker file?

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, miniconda

Hi I have a custom conda channel, something like `file://path_to_channel` and I want to install packages from that channel when building a docker images, something like:

```
...
RUN conda config add -channel file://...
RUN conda install mypackage
...
```

The problem here is that that file path seems not to be mounted to the docker image at build time.

My question is, apart from copying the whole channel into the docker image, is there another way we can install python package from custom file based channel, in the Dockerfile, at build time.

---

**My answer**

The answer down below is correct, docker do support runtime mount now. But I did not go down this path as we are on an older docker.

To bypass this I setup an http server to serve the files. This is extremely easy if you use node or python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is recently possible using the `RUN --mount` command. (It may still even be experimental.) You can find some examples [here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md).

An alternative is to serve the files using a local web server.

Comment: Didn't go this way as we are on an older docker which does not support run time mount. So I setup an http server instead. But still is a good answer.